# Is there a way to get the addresses of valid signers?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm wondering is there is a way to interact with the smart contract because we need to know who is managing the safe. We just want to get a list of the addresses allowed to sign a multisig transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getOwners` method on the smart contract:
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/OwnerManager.sol#L136

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://gnosis-safe.io/app/ and act as you would like to load an existing safe. Select the network on which the Safe was created, and then provide the address of safe. Gnosis should be able to display you the owners of this safe.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for Gnosis hosted contracts:

**Web Browser:**

`https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:<ADDRESS>`

**Etherscan:**

`Contract` tab --> `Read Contract` button will display value of `getOwnwers` call