# How to get owners of a Safe after deploying a smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

[image]

I am getting an error while logging the owner1 when running the script which prints the JSON_RPC on the terminal. How do i get the owners who were involved in deploying the Safe contract

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122814/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-addresses-of-valid-signers

Comment: So does this mean , the smart contract i first had i will have to deploy another smart contract  which has  SelfAuthorized in it ?